# Merge [double-quotes] into [quotes] - or delete both

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

Do we really need both [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) and [double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-quotes) tags? Come to think of it, do we even need one? They feel like meta-tags to me. They belong in the title or description.

> **[quotes]** ( x 1028 )
> Computer programming languages' facility for embedding text in source code, also known as String literals
>
> **[double-quotes]** ( x 373 )
> Questions related to the use of double-quotes in different programming languages.

Comment: Just came across quotes . . . seems pretty useless

Comment: The "quoting" appears useless as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would say, let's get rid of both of them, it's no more useful than having a [comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comma) tag for questions involving commas.  Which apparently we also have . . . Oh my.  I'm afraid to search for other punctuation marks, it already looks like we have two thousand questions to clean up.